# Redis sentinel local cluster setup in windows

Tags: redis, redis-sentinel

I'm trying to set up a redis-sentinel cluster locally. I'm running `Redis-64.2.8.4` on windows . I'd like to set up a master with 2 slaves as that will mirror my live environment.

I'm running

```
redis-server.exe sentinel.conf --sentinel
```

With this configuation

```
----
maxheap 64MB

sentinel monitor mymaster 127.0.0.1 7000 2
sentinel down-after-milliseconds mymaster 60000
sentinel failover-timeout mymaster 180000
sentinel parallel-syncs mymaster 1
----
```

But then I just get a repeated log of this

```
wait3() returned a pid (-1) we can't find in our scripts execution queue!
```

I've read through the [docs](http://redis.io/topics/sentinel) but to be honest I'm not much the wiser on what I should be doing here.  Do I specify all the servers in the configuration?

Comment: ever get it running to your satisfaction?

Answer (score 2):

No need to specify all the servers in the configuration file. We need to specify only the master host address and port number.I configured the sentinel with redis version -2.8.12 as per  link and it work.
[Link](http://tom.meinlschmidt.org/2013/12/20/redis-sentinel-setup/)

Answer (score -2):

Did you get this from NuGet?  I had the same issue but when I pulled it from github it solved my issues.